# How to count number of files and directories recursively in a given directory

Tags: command-line

I can find number of files recursively in a given directory

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

I can find number of directories recursively in a given directory

```
find . -type d | wc -l
```

But what I want a single command that shows number of files and directories  recursively in a given directory in the same time.

The output would be something like

```
6 directories, 14 files
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`tree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tree.1):

```
$ tree foo
foo
├── bar
│   ├── baz
│   └── foo3
└── foo2

2 directories, 2 files
```

Or you can combine `find` and `awk`:

```
find foo -type d -printf "d\n" -o -type f -printf "f\n" | awk '/f/{f++}/d/{d++}END{printf "%d directories, %d files\n", d, f}'
```

Or, generalizing:

```
find foo -printf "%y\n" | awk '/f/{f++}/d/{d++}END{printf "%d directories, %d files\n", d, f}'
```

If you don't mind concise output:

```
find foo -printf "%y\n" | sort | uniq -c
```

This will count one more directory than `tree` - the starting directory is not counted in `tree`'s output.

Comment: Nice, i found it this time by chance. lol anyway just 8 minuets and mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```
d=$(find . -type d | wc -l)
f=$(find . -type f | wc -l)
echo "There are $d directories and $f files"
```

In my case, the output is `There are 459 directories and 2352 files`

HTH

Comment: This would be more than one command. anyway +1 for your effort

Comment: Oh, it marks . and .. as well, which is wrong. I take it back.

Comment: This was useful. I'm using it after using `scp -r` to copy a folder (recursively) of files from Mac to PC on the same network. Unfortunately, although the number of directories is a match, I see a mismatch in number of files and in file sizes. I think that often happens between Mac and PC, but I don't know why (or how otherwise to double-check that my copying of files from Mac to PC was successful).

Comment: New question: https://superuser.com/questions/1462861/diff-directory-contents-from-mac-to-pc-on-same-network